# Edge Detection Along Blood Vessel in Matlab

Tags: matlab, edge-detection

I am trying to specify a line across a blood vessel in an image, and then have matlab specify the edges of the vessel (which are contained within the line). The next part will be comparing changes in the distance between these edges over time (so across 1000x more images).

I have tried the following code to get started:

`I = imread('Obj1.tif');
imshow(I,[]);
improfile`

And I was looking at available methods to detect the edges from intensity along that line that gets plotted (tangents, maxima/minima etc) but I am not convinced this is the best method. I looked into other tools on matlab such as the Canny Method, Sobel etc, but the examples for all of these only show how to detect edges throughout the entire image. My coding skills are not sufficient to have the algorithms specified along a single line of the users choosing. Methods that I have looked at on pubmed also seem more complicated then perhaps I need.

Does anybody have any ideas or suggestions from the point that I am currently at?

Thank you

Comment: Can you share a sample image from the data?

Comment: I need 10 reputation before I can post a sample image :( 
I could email it possibly?

Comment: @user2073640 but u can post image outside, e.g. at [imgur](http://imgur.com), and post link here.

Comment: Sounded like you are trying to measure the size of the blood vessels? Why not use segmentation and evaluate the thickness instead?

Comment: Hi, I apologize for the late reply. Here is the image in question http://imgur.com/bH3r8Ro. 

As for segmentation, Doesn't that overcomplicate the task? If I have an intensity profile across the line, Couldn't I use edge detection with that information?